# How to Display Data to Listview from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have two activity (DetailProduct and Wishlist) and i want to display data from DetailProduct to Wishlist, in here i using SharedPreferences for put data from DetailProduct to Wishlist.

This is my activity DetailProduct

```
wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String imgpicaso = getIntent().getStringExtra("aaa");
        String vardetailed = getIntent().getStringExtra("acb");
        String thisname = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("abb");
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent tambah = new Intent(DetailProduct.this, Wishlist.class);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = DetailProduct.this.getSharedPreferences("baba", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor shreditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            shreditor.putString("aaa", imgpicaso);
            shreditor.putString("name", thisname);
            shreditor.putString("abb", text);
            shreditor.commit();
            startActivity(tambah);
        }
    });
```

[This is img DetailProduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLYma.png)

[This is img Wishlist, please open this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmQP0.png)

And this is file Wishlist.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wishlist);
    setTitle("Your Wishlist");

    ImageView resultgmb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultgmb);
    TextView detailtok = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailtok);
    TextView resulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
    Button bayarwish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    Button hapus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("baba", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imgpicaso = sharedPreferences.getString("aaa", "");
    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(imgpicaso).into(resultgmb);
    String detailtext = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
    detailtok.setText(detailtext);
    String text = sharedPreferences.getString("ccc", "");
    resulttext.setText("$: " +text);

    listproduct = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listproduct);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listproduct.setAdapter(arr);

    arr.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

this is xml Wishlist

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</SearchView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relone"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"
        android:id="@+id/resultgmb"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="setext"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/detailtok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="setdescription"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailtok"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/resulttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/resulttext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CHECK"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DELETE"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listproduct"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Are you aware you can pass the data in the Intent when you launch your second activity?

Comment: Can you give me example tutorial? I want to display data to listview from SharedPreferences when button click

Answer (score 1):

As @sark9012 pointed out, you might want to use Intent Data rather than shared preferences for that purpose. [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable--cms-29559) is a tutorial on that.

### Edit

Although I'd really advise against using Shared Preferences data for the purpose you're looking for, it seems you got the code correct for retrieving the data from the Shared Preferences, what you might be missing out on is populating the ListView. This is the code you sent us:

```
listproduct = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listproduct);
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listproduct.setAdapter(arr);

arr.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I don't really see you populating the adapter with the data retrieved, so you might want to have a look into that. Check [this example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) from CodePath on how to setup the ListView with an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: tutorial not working, i want to display to listview from SharedPreferences. You have Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Generate comma separated string and store that in shared preference

while storing to SP.

like string1 = a1+","a2+","a3;

while retrieving from SP.

like array[] = string1.split(",");

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);